# argparse with optional value with quoted "--options --for --other --cmd"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to pass arguments directly to a command executed in my python script.  The script itself does not need to evaluate or manipulate the arguments to be passed to the command.

```
./cookbooks.py vendor -o "--delete"
```

Unfortunately, argparse recognizes the -- in the quoted string as an attempt to provide an optional argument instead of a value and an error is returned, "error: argument -o/--options: expected one argument".  It considers no value was provided for -o.

I simply want to append whatever is passed and not hinder the operators ability to use the underlying command. In below snippet, the `options` variable is supposed to be the quoted value of whatever.

```
cmd = ' '.join(["berks", "vendor", dir, options])
subprocess.call(cmd, cwd=entry.path, shell=True)
```

My parse argument is defined as below.  I have also tried with `type=str`.

```
parser.add_argument("-o", "--options",
                    help="berks vendor or knife cookbook upload options passed directly to the command")
```

Is it possible to indicate to argparse to accept quoted values as is?

Comment: the quotation marks are for shell, python receives raw strings

Comment: Typically when you're stopping giving arguments to one thing and starting to provide arguments that should go to something *it* calls, you'd use `--`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Though keep in mind that `argparse` does not natively support that pattern; you have to manually manipulate `sys.argv` to split the args into two groups and only pass the first group to `parse_args`.

Comment: @0x5453 No, `argparse` supports `--` just fine; you just need to define the parser to expect positional arguments.

Comment: @chepner Is that true?  I wrote a script with passthrough args a couple years ago and I remember running into a lot of problems trying to get `argparse` to separate them correctly.  (IIRC there were problems because the sub-script had args that could match both parsers, and the outer script would greedily consume those args even if they came after a `--`?  Maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: @0x5453 [Yes, it's true](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current definition, you can call your script with

```
./cookbooks.py vendor -o=--delete
```

Since `--` doesn't start an argument, `argparse` doesn't see it as an option, only as part of a name-value pair to split on `=`.

Comment: Thank you. The following two methods worked.
`./cookbooks.py vendor -o=--delete`
`./cookbooks.py vendor -o="--delete --something"`

Comment: I've also successfully used the action='append' in the add_argument definition and joined the array into a string. `./cookbooks.py vendor -o=--delete -o=--something`.

Comment: If you need to build a single string, be sure to document that carefully, so that the user is not confused about whether `-o="--delete foo" -o "--something"` creates an argument list with 2 or 3 arguments.

Comment: Thank you.  I decided that defining the argument as follows is going to work best for my application.  `parser.add_argument("-o", "--options", default='',
                        help="arguments passed directly to the command, required format: -o=\"args\", i.e. -o=\"--delete --only groupa\"")`. Which prints as `arguments passed directly to the command, required format: -o="args", i.e. -o="--delete --only groupa"`